# Is there a third party component that helps track down delphi missing files in project?

Tags: delphi, ide, code-completion

Most of the time finding missing file in project that has a central repository is very silly. It's something a computer could do much faster than me as a programmer. However I have no idea how to create this thing inside Delphi ide, since I don't know any open source interface for Delphi for this thing(such as eclipse plugins).

So I'm asking: is there a plugin that knows how to locate missing files in project, and give suggestions,to the programmer that can chose the most correct, or manually finding the missing file?

update: it could also include identifying the unit that needs to be added to the uses, after calling an object from another unit.

Comment: Are missing files in a project something that happens a lot? Seems rather strange.

Comment: How on earth would this magic tool work out which unit contained the missing object? Programming is something done by humans rather than by computers.

Comment: @David many non-Delphi IDEs have this "magic tool", and provide a shortcut to add all necessary file/class references (such as imports), and in case of ambiguities display a selection list so the programmer can pick the right one.

Comment: @mjn VS resolve using works with standard framework classes. Does it offer to resolve with random files located anywhere on the machine?

Comment: @David I assume you are reffering for the main problem and not the update. they could offer to specify the Paths of the folders containing code to search within. BTW in windows 7 the search takes less then a second with "Search everything". try it. About the update, the file must be listed within the project files, or components, which the delphi knows there location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is - at least for the part described in your update:

> identifying the unit that needs to be added to the uses, after calling
>   an object from another unit

The **Refactoring | Find Unit ...** context menu item can be used to quickly locate the unit for a type or symbol. Right-click on the wiggly-underlined text and choose “Refactoring | Find Unit…“. A dialog will present all unit(s) which contain the unknown type or symbol, and a mouse click adds the selected unit to the uses list of the current file. It does not work always but if it does, it saves many manual steps. (Found [here](http://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/delphi-ide-features-tips-and-tricks/))

Answer (score 1):

Delphi 6 was able to do this with some tweaking. See http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27913